# "____________ anyone call, please take a message."

Tags: conditional-constructions

"____________ anyone call, please take a message."

1. did
2. should
3. could
4. might

Could you tell me which one is correct answer and why please?

Comment: Please describe your own reasoning and provide your own best guesses in questions.

Comment: Normally I only would say " If anyone calls, please take a message"..

Comment: But from the four given options, which would you pick?

Comment: I think I would go for "should".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct word to use in this sentence is "should".

Should anyone call, take a message.

In formal English, we use "should" instead of "if" for describing a situation that may possibly happen.

Comment: Thanks for answer.If I would ask you to rewrite this sentence then, can you say " If anybody should call, please take a message."

Comment: That's kind of halfway between formal & colloquial; ends up being a bit awkward, though not really wrong. Colloquial would be "If anyone calls…" Formal is "Should anyone call…"

Comment: @Murat, I agree with Tetsujin that we usually say "if anyone calls" in spoken English.